# How to copy sql result from one variable to other

Tags: php

How to copy sql result from one variable to other **without arrays and foreach** in `PHP`.

```
$query="Select * from table";
$res1=mysql_query($query);
$res2=$res1; // I need somethink like this, simply, like in other languages
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res1)) {
echo $row['Id'];
}
echo '<br>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res2)) {
echo $row['Id'];
}
```

First while will print id, **second not print**.

Comment: So what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `SELECT` queries `mysql_query()` returns a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) on success, which is a special variable holding a reference to the result set. In this statement `$res2=$res1;` you're only copying the reference to another variable, not the actual result set. And in the first `while` loop you have already iterated the result set, hence assigning the resource to another variable won't reset it back.

But you can use `mysql_data_seek()` function to adjust the result pointer to point to the beginning of the result set so that you could iterate through it again.

Here's the reference:

- [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
$query="Select * from table";
$res=mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $row['Id'];
}
echo '<br />';

mysql_data_seek($res, 0);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $row['Id'];
}
```

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: I am amazed. Learned new thing. +10 FROM MY SIDE

Comment: @A-2-A I am happy that you are amazing on my question.

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul I will try it, thank you +10 and may be +15 if will work

Comment: I am amazed with the answer. it tell me new thing. But yes your question is really good. +10 to you also i gave. Please mark this answer, i insist

Comment: `Please mark this answer` how?
I copy variable to variable in other languages and will wery dumped when I can't do this in `PHP` in this case.

Comment: Why all say don't use `mysql_ is deprecate` . I know and I easy can ad link to db and add an `i` and use mysqli_query($link,''). But this thingh that all say don't, don't  every where is terible, is ...

Comment: @Mitch Actually it's written to let the future visitors know that the `mysql_` extensions are no longer supported. But sometimes it's also helpful for OP, if ofcourse he/she doesn't know it already.

Comment: _For SELECT queries mysql_query() returns a resource on success, and you can't copy the resource to another variable like this, $res2=$res1;._ Why can't I copy one variable (here resource) to another?

Comment: @SohelAhmedM Perhaps my answer needs a little more refinement. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[you can check on this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$temp_result = $result;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($temp_result)) {
// do stuff with $row
}
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($temp_result)){
// do other stuff with $row
}
```

Comment: copy paste and just variable change

Comment: @Ankit Gupta Ok, I understand when read first answer, but thank you also for atention. +10

Comment: May be you put effort for this but learn something from above one, how to gave an answer. Because whenever any one see he thing it just a copy paste.